# Is it possible to mask NaN values in keras LSTM's Label-set?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have an LSTM Dataset. Some labels contain NaNs at the end, which cant be backward filled (because theres no values after them) and foreward-filling them would make no sense (since the labels timestamp will be deprecated in a 'nearer future'-timestamp (=missing value locatoin) compared to its acutal timeindex)

So: is there a way to mask NaN-values in the LABEL-set(/Output-set)? (because sample_weights is for Input data only as it seems).

Comment: Why don't you just skip those samples which have `NaN` values during data preparation. You will need something similar to [this](https://github.com/AtrCheema/dl_ts_prediction/blob/master/docs/using_intervals.py). Another solution would be to write custom training loop and by using masking, you can skip loss calculation for those samples whose lables are NaNs. A similar example is shwn [here](https://github.com/AtrCheema/dl_ts_prediction/blob/master/docs/run_custom_train_loop.py)

Comment: A) I read the github docs, but dont understand what `interval` does, could you explain
@AtherCheema

Comment: B) Skipping whole samples is no option. I more thought of something like providing a mask 2d array for Labels only. Is that possible

Comment: What do you mean by skipping is not an option? If the labels for certain samples/examples are not available, there is no way you can calculate loss for those samples. You have to either skip those samples during data preparation or you have to skip those samples during loss calculation. For second case, you will to write custom training loop which skips those samples during loss calculation. I can provide you a working example for both of these cases if you like using `dl_ts_prediction` provided this is what you want?

Comment: so it is impossible if I have a label-sample like  [ 0.123, 0.437, 0.891, NaN, 1,497, 1.1 ]. to train only on the valid numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish data masking via a Keras Masking layer:https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/masking/.

Layers that following the masking layer *and support masking* (the LSTM layer does) will skip samples / steps where *all* features equal the masking value for that step.

However, since the Masking layer checks for equality between the mask value and the data, you can't use NaN as a masking value since NaN does not equal itself, (np.nan == np.nan is false).

Instead, you can use the Masking layer by first converting your NaN values to 0 (the default mask value) or another value if explicitly specified as the masking value when generating the Masking layer:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

# your example timesteps
ex_data = np.array([0.123, 0.437, 0.891, np.nan, 1.497, 1.1])

# reshape your example timesteps into a 3D matrix (1 sample x 6 timesteps x 1 feature per timestep)
data =  np.reshape(ex_data, (1, 6, 1))

# set NaN values to 0, which is the default masking value
data[np.isnan(data)] = 0
masked_data = layers.Masking()(data)

print(masked_data._keras_mask)
```

Returns:

```
tf.Tensor([[ True  True  True False  True  True]], shape=(1, 6), dtype=bool)
```

Comment: "NaN does not equal itself" - this saved me a lot of pain